# Python Memory Errors with Itertool

Tags: python-3.x, performance, memory, optimization, python-itertools

I have a small Bruteforce program to do for school.
I've made a program, but when I run my code, A Memory Error appear...
Here is the message from my IDE :

> passwords = [''.join(word) for word in itertools.product(Alphabet, repeat=CharLength)]
>   MemoryError

I suppose most of the errors are due to how I use loop no ? 
As a noob I never meet this type of error... I giving you 1 more information, I'm running my code on Windows

How can I Optimize my code and how to fix too ?
    Here is my code :

```
import hashlib
import itertools


#possible characters in user password
Alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-_.;#@")
#minimum password value
CharLength = 6

#getting passwords and username from shadow file
with open("shadow_test", "r") as ins:
    array = []
    users = []
    passwd = []
    #getting everyline from shadow file into an array
    for line in ins:
        array.append(line)
    #saving only username and passwords
    for pw in array:
        str(pw)
        r= pw.split(":")
        users.append(r[0])
        passwd.append(r[1])

    list = []
    #removing passowrd with * or !
    for mdp in passwd:
        if mdp != '*' and mdp != '!':
            str(mdp)
            list.append(mdp)
            # trying to Bruteforce
            for _ in range(12):
                passwords = [''.join(word) for word in itertools.product(Alphabet, repeat=CharLength)]

                print(*passwords)
                for pswd in passwords:
                    hash_object = hashlib.md5(str.encode(pswd)).hexdigest()
                    # hash_object.update(*passwords.encode('utf-8'))
                    generatedpassword = '$1$' + hash_object

                    for compare in list:
                        for user in users:
                            #print('on cherche le Mot de passe : ' + compare +' pour ' +user)
                            #print('mot de passe MD5 généré : ' +generatedpassword)
                            #print('mot de passe clair généré : ' +pswd)


                            if generatedpassword == list:
                                print('Le Mot de passe pour' + user + ' est : ' + compare)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
passwords = [''.join(word) for word in itertools.product(Alphabet, repeat=CharLength)]
```

Here you're creating a list that is over 50**6 long. Of course you're going to get a memory error. Use a generator instead:

```
passwords = (''.join(word) for word in itertools.product(Alphabet, repeat=CharLength))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `password` list as-is will have approximately 100 billion entries, so you would need upwards of 1 TB of memory to be able to hold it.  Instead of making it a list, leave it as a generator to loop over later:

```
passwords = (''.join(word) for word in itertools.product(Alphabet, repeat=CharLength))
```

(Although for 100 billion entries, you'll probably be waiting a while.)